# Angular multi step form - Two-way binding or FormDataService

Tags: angular, forms, multi-step

My question is a design one:

I want to implement a multi step form. So if I have 4 steps for example, I have 4 components where each one of them is a step in a multi step form

There is one parent component which swtiches the view inside it with the active step component

**Option #1**

Use two-way binding between the parent component and each one of the child components. Upon form confirmation (last step) I can use the form data in my parent component. For example:

```html
<div class="tab-content">
  <personal-step 
    *ngIf="currentStep == 'personalStep'"
    [(personal)]="personalData"></personal-step>
  <work-step 
    *ngIf="currentStep == 'workStep'"
    [(work)]="workData"></work-step>
  <address-step 
    *ngIf="currentStep == 'addressStep'"
    [(address)]="addressData"></address-step>
  <confirmation-step 
    *ngIf="currentStep == 'confirmationStep'"
    (confirm)="formConfirmed()"></confirmation-step>
</div>
```

**Option #2**

Use FormDataService which will be injected to each one of the child components. The rendering of the steps will be done with the routing mechanism. Upon form confirmation (last step) I can use the injected FormDataService in the ConfirmationComponent or in my parent component and use the form data

```html
<div class="tab-content">
  <!-- Routed view  -->
  <router-outlet></router-outlet>
</div>
```

And a FormDataService

```js
export class FormDataService {
  private formData: FormData = new FormData();
  getPersonal(): Personal {
    return this.formData.personal
  }

  setPersonal(data: Personal) {
    this.formData.personal = data;
  }

  getWork(): Work {
    return this.formData.work
  }

  setWork(data: Work) {
    this.formData.work = data;
  }

  getAddress(): Address {
    return this.formData.address
  }

  setAddress(data: Address) {
    this.formData.address = data;
  }
}
```

I was wondering if you can help me find pros and cons to each method, and share with which way would you go

Thanks

Comment: I suggest you to have a look at the stepper api from the official ComponentDevelopmentKit (@angular/cdk/stepper). You can finde the documentation here https://material.angular.io/cdk/stepper/overview and a working example how you can use it here: https://material.angular.io/components/stepper/overview

Comment: @SplitterAlex Thanks for your response. I prefer not to include material design in my app. Is it something I can still use without having the material design style (taking only the logic without the view)?

Comment: The `ComponentDevelopmentKit` comes only with the functionality. There is no graphical interface, css etc included. It is up to you how the Stepper will look like. As you are using Angular I highly recommend to use `@angular/cdk` because it provides useful functionality out of the box. And if you don't want the ui components just don't install `@angular/material`. Just add `import {CdkStepperModule} from '@angular/cdk/stepper';` to your prefered module. Checkout this article for a basic introduction: https://blog.angular.io/a-component-dev-kit-for-angular-9f06e3b4b3b4

Comment: Bravo! thanks a lot